# VISUAL STUDIO CODE Toggle Line Comment not WORKING ANNOYING

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

Would be great if you can help with the following.

I find Visual Studio Code a good product for my software development needs. However, for me it is completely useless because the toggle line comment never works. I have installed the intellJ Idea keybindings cause I am too accustomed to it but Code studio rejects simple toggle line comment. What is worse, I am able to comment the line but with Ctrl+, whereas I expect that it should work with Ctrl+/ or the one defined with extension CTRL+NumpadDivide..... Also since Ctrl+\ is linked to split window it is a mess for me.

The json keybindings file is empty. I deleted everything there. I am Using Ubuntu 20.04, However my keyboard, because I changed it is Latin American Spanish..... I don't remeber that this key binding has ever worked when I had English Keyboard

Thanks

Comment: CTRL+K+C and CTRL+K+U ?

Comment: you can debug key bindings and see which keycode is actually received and which command VSC uses

Comment: @rioV8 nice! how ?

Comment: read the key bind doc page of VSC

Comment: I am having problem with the keyboard layout